# how the loads are calculated on nodes in this link https://iota-nodes.net/

Tags: iota-network

I need to show the load of the full nodes. it appeared in the above link. I am wondering if the javascript code is available. thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try asking the author of the site, `@kevmiota on the Iota Discord`?

Comment: When manually querying those nodes that currently have a nonzero value and comparing to the node info, I assume it is the result of the `transactionsToRequest` field of the node info when the node was queried last.